# Haskell Snappy パッケージの decompress を利用した場合の例外処理について

Tags: haskell, exception

Snappy パッケージの下記 [decompress](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/snappy-0.2.0.2/docs/src/Codec-Compression-Snappy-Lazy.html) を利用する際、どのようにコーディングを行えば例外処理が出来るでしょうか？

```
decompress :: ByteString -> ByteString

Decompress data in the Snappy format.
If the input is not compressed or is corrupt, an exception will be thrown.
```

`try` を利用した場合 Left になると思ったのですが、結果は Right となってします。

```
ghci> import Data.ByteString
ghci> import Control.Exception
ghci> import Codec.Compression.Snappy
ghci> let bs = "test" :: ByteString
ghci> decompress bs
"*** Exception: user error (Codec.Compression.Snappy.decompress: corrupt input )
ghci> try (return $ decompress bs)::IO (Either SomeException ByteString)
Right "*** Exception: user error (Codec.Compression.Snappy.decompress: corrupt input )
```

Comment: related: [How do I correctly use Control.Exception.catch in Haskell? - Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18052619/how-do-i-correctly-use-control-exception-catch-in-haskell)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

この挙動はsnappyライブラリとは直接関係なく、Haskellの評価戦略によるものです。

```
λ:2> import Control.Exception
λ:3> try (return undefined) :: IO (Either SomeException ())
Right *** Exception: Prelude.undefined
```

`return`は引数の評価を強制しないので`try (return undefined)`の`undefined`は評価されることなく`Right undefined`となり、GHCiが`Right`まで出力した後、初めて中身が評価され例外が上がります。これを防ぐには`Control.Exception.evaluate`で評価を強制すればよいのです。

```
λ:4> try (evaluate undefined) :: IO (Either SomeException ())
Left Prelude.undefined
```

全く同じ内容がReal World Haskellの19章でも[取り上げられています](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/error-handling.html#errors.exceptions.lazy)。